# Using NVL2 and NULLIF in Scala SparkSQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use the NVL2 and NULLIF spark sql functions in my scala-spark code but it does not work.

This is what I see - 
The below statement works fine and returns the correct result

```
spark.sql("select columnName, NULLIF(columnName, 'abc') as status from df")
```

But, this statement fails and returns below error-

```
df.withColumn('status', NULLIF(columnName, 'abc'))
```

`error: not found: value NULLIF`

I am seeing similar issue while trying to use NULLIF, NVL2, LEAST and GREATEST functions in withColumn() syntax. Am I missing something? I tried

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis._
```

in my scala code but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

Scala Spark functions library do not have these function but spark sql librry do have these functions. This is why you are not able to use as spark function API.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html

`isNull` function exists that can be combined with when/then clause to set values.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Please provide an example, of how to keep the old value without specifying it if it is non null

Comment: @PaulVelthuis , you can refer examples at https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#nullif . you have to call as sql statement. If you have dataframe, you can register temporary view and then can write select statement with nullif, nvl, nvl2 function based on need.